# Error when using Ludwig: ValueError: Unexpected keyword arguments: `confidence_penalty`, `positive_class_weight`, `robust_lambda`

Tags: tensorflow, ludwig

When I use the Ludwig package to build a tabular type classification, the error is happened as following.

ValueError: Unexpected keyword arguments: `confidence_penalty`, `positive_class_weight`, `robust_lambda`

The detailed informtion: ludwig 0.7.4

[image]

How can I solve it? In fact, I only selected a few features for modeling.